# how to click on those boxes using selenium

Tags: image, selenium, whatsapp, send

how to click on those boxes using selenium, I've tried every kind of thing nothing works.help, please
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YACnD.png)

Comment: If you right click on it and press 'inspect' then post the image of the code it will help us help you

Comment: Code trials? Relevant HTML? Erorrs?